# AWS API Gateway + Lamda - how to handle 1 million requests per second

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

we would like to create serverless architecture for our startup and we would like to support up to 1 million requests per second and 50 millions active users. How can we handle this use case with AWS architecture?

Regarding to AWS documentation API Gateway can handle only 10K requests/s and lamda can process 1K invocations/s and for us this is unacceptable.

How can we overcome this limitation? Can we request this throughput with AWS support or can we connect somehow to another AWS services (queues)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Those numbers you quoted are the default account limits. Lambda and API Gateway can handle more than that, but you have to send a request to Amazon to raise your account limits. If you are truly going to receive 1 million API requests per second then you should discuss it with an AWS account rep. Are you sure most of those requests won't be handled by a cache like CloudFront?

Comment: For sure we can cache some GET requests, but in our case we will use a lot of POST/PUT requests and we need to be sure that it will be handled by AWS

Comment: AWS support has a form for requesting rate limit increases.  A request for 1 million rps will result in the API Gateway team engaging with you to understand your use case and work with you to increase your limits and to load test to the desired level.

Answer (score 1):

The gateway is NOT your API Server. Lambda's are the bottleneck.

While the gateway can handle 100000 messages/sec (because it is going through a message queue), Lambdas top out at around 2,200 rps even with scaling (https://amido.com/blog/azure-functions-vs-aws-lambda-vs-google-cloud-functions-javascript-scaling-face-off/)

This differs dramatically from actually API framework implementations wherein the scale goes up to 3,500+ rps...
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with Application Load Balancer.
It is limitless in terms of RPS and can potentially be even cheaper for a large number of requests. It does have fewer integrations with AWS services though, but in general, it has everything you need for a gateway.
https://dashbird.io/blog/aws-api-gateway-vs-application-load-balancer/